# Can you help identify a US paperback book that included Greg Bear's Blood Music?

Tags: story-identification, anthology-book, greg-bear

I read this book in highschool, no later than 1992. His short story (it was only later expanded to a novel) was 1983. This would have been a science fiction anthology with multiple authors, as is typical for science fiction. If I had to guess, it'd be edited by Greenberg, but I don't remember that detail it's only a guess. The theme of the anthology was technology (but not necessarily biotech) and intelligence (AI and otherwise). I remember nothing of the cover art, the editor, or other authors' names/stories.

This will help me identify another story included within it, the details of which are too fuzzy to be a question of its own.

Given what I know of how the industry does these anthologies, there might be more than one candidate title, but it will be a short list (possibly as many as 3, but most likely just 1).

Comment: It's been anthologized *a lot*. You can see a list here http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?49380  The only one I saw by Greenberg was *The New Hugo Winners*

Comment: [ISFDb lists a few](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?49380); I have [*Tangents*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?36848), DAW's [*1984 World's Best*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?33546) **and** Dozois' [*Best of the Best*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?157211).  (Not to mention the original [*Analog*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?57148) publication...)  Oh, and (just for completeness?) I also have the full novel.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Thanks. I must have spent an hour on that site, trying to figure out how to get to that list. I'm looking for 1991's The New Hugo Winners, it is a Greenberg title, and another story in its story list confirms it as the one I want. And the story I was trying to identify is a John Varley of all things.

Comment: @JohnO "Press Enter ▮?"  You should have just asked about _that_; several people here would have been likely to recognize it instantly.

Comment: Glad it helped. I'll write it up as an answer.

Comment: @DavidW I remembered no details coherent enough to formulate a question around it? Wasn't the woman in it asian? I think she commits suicide (if that's even the right word) at the end of it.

Comment: Yes, that happens in Press Enter. It's also the only scifi story I know that features a TI-99/4 home computer, although the model name isn't called out IIRC.

Comment: @OrganicMarble The only thing science fiction about the TI-99 is the market research Texas Instruments used to justify manufacturing the thing. Their idiocy was my boon, after it hit the bargain bins mom was finally able to afford to get my brother and I a computer.

Comment: I bought three of the things for $100 each. It was my first home computer. Then I spent like a $1000 on the accessories: the expansion box, RAM, disk drives, etc. Good times.

Comment: @OrganicMarble No accessories for me. The dreaded cassette recorder was the only storage. It never worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possibly [The New Hugo Winners](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?281856)?

It contains the story and one of the editors was Greenberg.

ISFDB makes it possible to see the publications a short story has been printed in. Once the story is located (via author or whatever other search term), click on the title. A new page will load showing each of those, giving details such as the date, format, and type (anthology/magazine/etc). Unfortunately, language (if translated), isn't one of those details and must be inferred from the title of the publication.